# iOS-font-style text shadow with css using mix-blend-mode?

Tags: css, blending

I'm trying to create an iOs-style text-shadow using css. I need a blurry dark background around images that allows me to  If I apply something like this, I get a nice darker background that gives my text better contrast, regardless of the background color. The text is on a image and I don't know the color of the image.

```
h1{
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

This works nicely on darker images, but on lighter images, the blending is to strong. I would like to apply some blending. I found mix-blend-mode: darken, but it applies to the content, not the shadow, can I somehow apply this to the shadow?

Comment: If you post a working code snippet it will be easier for us to see and elaborate with

Comment: Yep, you have any example about are you trying. :)

Comment: Hrm, sorry for the external site, it uses the camera API... https://kaleidoskop.herokuapp.com/, the snippet isn't really working since it's not doing what I want it to do though...